# cy.select() can only be called on a <select>. Your subject is a: <div class="col-md-6">...</div>

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I am trying to select a value from multiselect dropdown via Cypress and using this

```
 cy.get(':nth-child(7) > .row > :nth-child(1)')
 .select('The Watermark at Cherry Hills', { force: true })
 .invoke('val')
 .should('0', 'The Watermark at Cherry Hills')
```

and failing it. Anyone can guide me how to handle this ?

```
<div data-vv-name="Community 1" class="">
   <div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown form-control">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i><input autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" name="" class="search">
      <div data-vss-custom-attr="" class="text default">Select community/s
      </div>
      <div tabindex="-1" class="menu hidden" style="display: none;">
         <div data-vss-custom-attr="" class="item">
            The Watermark at Cherry Hills
         </div>
         <div data-vss-custom-attr="" class="item">
            The Fountains at Albemarle
         </div>
         <div data-vss-custom-attr="" class="item">
            The Sapphire Valley
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the html of your dropdown ?

Comment: @AlapanDas Just added in question..

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to do a `click()` operation on the dropdown to expand it. Now using `each()` you can loop through all the elements of the dropdown, and using an `if` condition click the one you want to select.

```
cy.get('.search.selection.dropdown').click() 
cy.get('div.item').each(($ele) => {
    if ($ele.text() == "The Watermark at Cherry Hills") {
        cy.wrap($ele).click()
    }
})
```